# Is this a retain cycle(property)?

Tags: objective-c

I have two viewcontrollers(vcA and vcB), vcA it's parent for vcB(I added vcB over vcA with addChildViewController), in both controllers I have an object declared with strong argument. Before to present vcB I make somenthing vcB.myobject = self.myobject, can cause this a retain cycle?
It's better to use weak argument for object from vcB?

Comment: One thing to add - this is actually really easy to test. A quick heuristic I use to determine if a retain cycle exists (may not be perfect so your mileage may vary) but just put an NSLog in your view controller's `dealloc` method, and when you dismiss that view controller if there's a retain cycle it won't be called.

Comment: @Mike  I tested how you sugessted and method it's called, thanks

Answer (score 2):

It causes a retain cycle if the object has a strong reference to one of the view controllers. If the object doesn't have a strong reference to either view controller, then it doesn't cause a retain cycle.

Comment: Beat me to it. As long as the self.myObject doesn't have a strong ref back to the view controllers, you're fine.

Comment: @rob mayoff Thanks, I understand better now the concept.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a retain cycle. It's merely two objects (vcA and vcB) with strong references to a third object (`myObject`). That is normal and correct. Each will perform proper memory management on that third object, and it will not leak.

Comment: This what I thought first time but I wanted to be sure, thanks